# Testing pickadate with jest

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, pickadate, luxon

On a Rails project, we've got a date picker using `pickadate` v3.6.2.   Tests have been working for some time, but with a recent move away from `moment.js` to `luxon.js` some of the feature specs are failing.  IRL, the functionality works fine.  I think it's about how we're setting the date input.  I'm trying to get the right function to drive `capybara` to set the date input.

The date input is in a form element which has been initialized with

```
$("#the_date_input").pickadate()
```

and a consuming script works (IRL) as follows:

```
const startDateField = this.element.find(this.opts.the_date_inputs_field);
const datePicker = startDateField.pickadate('picker');
if (datePicker) {
  // this logs the correct value in the browser console
  console.log(datePicker.get('select', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
  ...
}
```

The date format in the browser looks like `12, October, 2020` - long presentable date format.

Our `capybara` code tries to set the value `Rails` default `to_date` string format, which I think is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
  page.execute_script("$('#the_date_input').val('#{start_date.to_date}');")
```

Do I need to format `val` as the long english date string?  or is there a better way with `pickadate` to just inject the value or set the value (with JS) in these tests.

Comment: The proper solution here is to stop using `execute_script` to interact with your page, and instead select dates in the pickadate widget just like the user would

Comment: True.  That would be better.  ugh... :D

Answer (score 0):

Though a better solution would be to build some code to interact with the date picker (like a normal user - as @Thomas Walpole mentions above), programmatically interacting with the date picker modal is tricky.

I found a solution - maybe not ideal - but you can use the `pickadate` `select` method to specify a date. This runs through the `pickdate` code to properly set the input value and whatever else is happening under the hood.

This is my capybara helper method:

```
def set_pickadate_date(pickadate_selector, date)
  page.execute_script("$('#{pickadate_selector}').pickadate('picker').set('select', [#{date.year}, #{date.month - 1}, #{date.day}]);")
end
```

I found this through the `pickadate` docs: https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-set-select

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at `<%= form.date_field :date_attribute %>` - it will use a native date picker, supported by all major browsers.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Sadly the product owner likes pickadate's interface better than the native which is why we're in this boat.  But good call out.